# How to use grep to find a class inside a folder?

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep all the cases where I have className=' that is larger than 20.
I was trying something like this

```
grep -ri '^className=.{20,}$' ~/foo/bar
```

How to properly do it?

Comment: ``'^className=.{20,}'`` - no space should appear after comma

Answer (score 0):

This helps

```
grep -rioe "className='.\{20,\}'" ~/foo/bar
```